# How does one use EXSLT modules in XMLSpy?

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt, xmlspy

I'm trying to use the EXSLT modules (specifically, math), in an XQuery document. How do I enable support for this in XMLSpy? Where would I place the downloaded EXSLT libraries to make XMLSpy aware of them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the XMLSpy processor supports the EXSLT extensions.  There's a facility in spy to choose your own processor, and I would recommend you use Saxon, then read the [Saxon docs](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/exslt.html) on how to use EXSLT.

That, however, won't fix that you are trying to use XSLT defined extentions in xquery.  It may be you could somehow get the xquery processor to refer to them, but you almost certainly want to use Xslt instead of xquery.

The only reason I would advise anybody to use xquery is if you are working against a native xml database.

Is there any other reason you're using xquery over xslt?

Comment: As of 01/16/2020 the link is dead.

Comment: Looks like it's now located at: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/functions/exslt.html

Comment: Then why don't you edit your answer with the working one? Just asking...